# HTML form tag with no attributes - any reason not to?

Tags: forms, html

At risk of sounding like a fool - The html (html5) designers at our firm keep handing me functional mocks with form tags that have no attributes...

```
<form>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
</form>
```

Every time I see this I lose hope in humanity just a little more. But I don't know if I should round them all up and lecture them on form attributes and why we need them since I can't seem to find any documentation that says they are "required." By default I know the form tag will assume things, like method and action, but I prefer those attributes are in place rather than omitted. It's just how it's always been for those of us who have been writing HTML since it began.

So the general question is - Is there anything wrong (however you wish to define that) with using the form tag with no attributes? If your intended action is the current page and the intended method is get, then what argument is there for including versus excluding the default attributes? Or assigning it an id that you don't use?

I expected to see this:

```
<form id="search_form" action="" method="get">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
</form>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will depend on the DOCTYPE you are validating against. For example in HTML 4.01 Transitional and Strict, the `action` attribute is required whereas the `method` attribute is optional.

In HTML 5 both attributes are optional.

Comment: That much is not too difficult to find, but it is difficult to find anything that mentions whether or not a form tag can be empty entirely. Back in the day, name was deprecated for form tag and id was required to validate. Now I don't see anything in particular stating either should be there.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issue with not having an `id` and `action` attributes on a form is that if you have more than one form on the page it is very difficult to say which one is being referred to - in either client *or* server code.

As James Montagne mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9284694/1583) for HTML 4.01 transitional the `action` attribute is required.

As a general issue, I personally would always be explicit about the `id`, `action` and `method` - keeps these important attributes in the open and makes the point that they were not forgotten.

Comment: That was pretty much my sentiment on the issue. I like to declare them because it makes sense to do so - for lack of a better way of saying it. When they leave it off I don't know if it is because they think that is the right way to do it or if they assume I am going to fill it in with the right info. But we don't hire html guys to leave holes and require full audits. Otherwise we'd just do it ourselves and save some time.

Comment: @KaiQing - If that's your requirement from them, talk to them about it.

Comment: True - in this post all I was really looking for was some kind of documentation stating that form tags actually needed something in them. Otherwise, my argument is merely opinion or preference. It seems in this case it is just that. The form will submit with no attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that action is required by the html 4 standard.

```
 action      %URI;          #REQUIRED
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html

Comment: And yet, most browsers will be happy to default the value to the current URL (assuming quirks mode).

Comment: True, but technically for the html to validate that should be an empty action, not no action at all.

Comment: Right - I forgot to mention new mocks are always in html5 doctype. I saw the html4 #REQUIRED but dismissed its relevance since we don't declare html4 anymore.